# Create a custom CSS textarea box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This isn't much of a how do i fix this problem,it's more of a can you point me in the right direction.

So the thing is that i want to know ,i've seen several textarea fields which when you input some value inside it like,and click save it stores it and starts using it.

```
.div{
 background:black;
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

you get the point.What can i search for on google to find that?what language does it use obviously it's inside an HTML5 and i'd guess it's backed up by php somehow which stores the values in the database.

I've seen it on most platform like opencart,wordpress,magento etc etc.can someone give me a pointer on what to look for?

so basically I guess how to controll a stylesheet or a javascript file trough a browser i guess?

**EDIT**
It's like this

https://teamtreehouse.com/library/wordpress-customizer-api/custom-wordpress-customizer-settings/custom-css-textarea-in-the-theme-customizer

On around 7-th second.See how he inputs CSS code inside a box and it affects the site,I want someone to point me where I can learn or atlaest pick up something that's similar to that.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more or give an example or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you would need to store the user input value from the textarea in a php variable. (See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) Then you would need to insert that info into a database of some sort (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp for example). 
And last but certainly not least, you would need to get the data from the database and put it into the textarea, which would look something like this

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($message); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, besides the normal css file like style.css, you include another css file. Say: style2.css which is an empty file. Then you use php to open and write the additional css to this file by:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Or to include a php file as stylesheet which retreive data from database:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style2.css.php">
```